# Using DbContext.FindBy not with a PK

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

**Objective:**
I have a table called Publication that contains Id, RecordId, EntityType and a couple other columns. I select all the records that need to be published to another database from that table. I then loop that collection to process the records and move the records to the other db.

**Background:**
The EntityType column is used to Identify the Set that the context needs to retrieve. I also use reflection to create a object of that type to see if it implements a certain type of interface. If the record being processed does implement that interface then I know that the RecordId for that record in the Publication table is not a PK in the Set() but rather a FK.

this code works fine when I am going after the PK values for EntityTypes that do not inherit the specific interface.

```
object authoringRecordVersion = PublishingFactory.AuthoringContext.Set(recordType.Entity.GetType()).Find(record.RecordId);
```

**Problem:**

DbContext.Set(EntityType).Find(PK) goes after the PrimaryKey value. How can I tell Set() to search like this sudo code example since 'Where' is not allowed

```
object authoringRecordVersion = PublishingFactory.AuthoringContext.Set(recordType.Entity.GetType()).Where(c => c.HeaderRecordId == record.RecordId)
```

**Update:**

I am working on Implementing the following. Will advise results tomorrow

```
var sql = "SELECT * from " + record.Entity + " WHERE HeaderRecordId = '" + record.RecordId + "'";
authoringRecordVersion = PublishingFactory.AuthoringContext.Set(recordType.Entity.GetType()).SqlQuery(sql).AsNoTracking();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.SqlQuery(sql).AsNoTracking();
```

does work effectively. Don't know why I didn't see this earlier.